# Automate sending emails from Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-client

I very often want to send emails from Gmail with only slight modifications of the body and subject (maybe changing the person's name) to 10 or 20 people (usually customers).  I try different subject lines too and other little differences to spark discussions with customers.

Is there some way that I can automate this?

Copying and pasting subjects, bodies and emails along with the slight modifications is tedious and time consuming.

I don't do this that often YET where I want to spend the time to write a full fledged emailing application for this purpose and I want everything done through Gmail so I can easily see the threads and have a better chance of email delivery with a personal feel.

Answer (score 2):

We have templates built into [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) that you can add message variables to (for customer name, etc etc) and you send the messages by sending JSON to our API via HTTP POST.

You'd have to build the scheduling on your end, but is this something you were looking for? Let me know!

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager for PostageApp)

Comment: PostageApp looks really great.  I just have to develop an emailing app around it.. PostageApp is probably what I'll need to use if the canned responses gmail labs product proves still too time consuming and I don't find any easier solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Let me know if there is anything I can help you out with in regards to PostageApp. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

See canned responses within gmail lab settings.

Comment: Very simple, but definitely helpful.  I guess I was hoping for more a template mechanism where maybe I could just enter a list of name-email pairs and the canned response would plug those in.

Comment: I've been using canned responses, it's not very helpful to be honest.  At least they should've allowed the subject to be part of the canned response.  As it is I still have to go back to another page and copy and paste the emails and subjects.  I end up copying the emails and just typing out the subjects (which can be long).  Also canned responses requires that I have to be focused in the body area having highlighted the entire body to replace it and get rid of my signature.

Comment: You should expand this answer. It's a valid answer, it's just short and not very instructive.